# How to capture screencast video and root not required?

Tags: screencast

I found a lot of solution to make a screencast on Android but each time the root is mandatory.

Does anyone have the solution without root?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're willing to use external hardware, one good option is an External HDMI capture card and a USB to HDMI cable.

For example a `Blackmagic Design : UltraStudio Mini Recorder` is only $145 for an HD-SDI and HDMI thunderbolt device, and a Micro USB to HDMI cable can go for as little as $10.

This way the recording does not affect the performance of your device or app. More expensive than an app on the device, but much more flexible.

Answer (score 2):

Well, the reason Screencast and similar apps require root permission is that the video data has to be accessed using the administrative privileges (i.e. roots access)

But you can always **use an app** such as [No Root Screen Recorder](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.screenrecnoroot) to video record your screen. But the problem with this option is that you have to connect your device to a windows computer in order to capture.

This is the only option which is available to given you have *no root access*.

Answer (score 0):

To record the screen on Android without having to connect the Android to some computer, one can use some video conference application that allows screen sharing on Android such as Google Meet or BlueJeans, and record the video conference. Example (I used BlueJeans): https://youtu.be/guiB_8-XLg8 ([I added a visual effect to see where I click on the screen](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/226210/12202)).

Answer (score 0):

One can use the application [Screenshot touch](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mdiwebma.screenshot) (free for basic features and with ads) to record video screencasts. Example work the free version: https://youtu.be/bf2GMkq38b4 (tested with Android 10 on Samsung Galaxy S9), recorded with the settings shown on the screenshot below, which I chose to be the maximum settings (which end up being 1440p at 50 FPS on YouTube):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[Android 11 comes with a native screen recorder](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Android_version_history&oldid=991563183#Android_11_(API_30)):

[image]

Answer (score -1):

[ASC](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.benzul.asc) is an app that allow you to record your screen without root, but only for non-Tegra devices.

I never tested because my Galaxy Nexus is not supported.

Answer (score -1):

The best and the most simple way and the more beautiful, How to Capture/Record Android Screen Without Root

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4K2UDfP4lN8&feature=youtu.be

Comment: Welcome to  Android Enthusiasts! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. Otherwise, your answer becomes useless in case the link dies.