# How to make screencasts on Samsung Galaxy SIII?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, samsung, 4.3-jelly-bean, screencast

Is it possible to make a screencast (video) with a Samsung Galaxy SIII?
I want to record what the screen looks like as the user interacts with
it. I know I can take a screenshot with Home+Power but I'm not sure
whether besides screenshots it is also possible to make screencasts.

Thanks.

Comment: I have not tried any of those, but for a starter (while waiting for good answers) you might wish to take a look into my list of apps for [Screen Recording](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/multimedia_video_screenrecording). Also worth a look: [other questions tagged `screencast`](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/screencast), e.g. [How to capture screencast video and root not required?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/50666/16575) / [Is it possible record videos of my screen?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/2951/16575)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Theres an app for that:
SCR free.
You will need root for this

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.iwobanas.screenrecorder.free

Comment: SCR Free moved to https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.iwobanas.screenrecorder.free2