# How can I add a visual effect on where I click on the screen on Android?

Tags: screen, android-10

How can I add a visual effect on where one clicks on the screen on Android?

Similarly to what can be done in Windows:

[image]

I don't see any `Show Touches` in `Developer Options`:

[image]

Comment: Developer Options -> Show Touches seems like a possible way, unless you're trying to do it for a single app.

Comment: @l3l_aze thank you, I don't see any `Show Touches` in `Developer Options`: https://i.stack.imgur.com/L7VQu.jpg

Comment: Interesting, usually Android's Developer Options has *a lot* more -- is this not Settings -> Developer Options, or is it a preview release, emulator, or Android-x86?

Comment: Screenshot is of Accessibility Settings Developer Options. You need to full `adb` Developer Settings. Settings (Gear icon) -> (at bottom) Developer Options -> Input section, Show Taps.

Comment: @l3l_aze I use the Android 10 on Samsung Galaxy S9. I don't have Settings -> Developer Options. I'm starting to wonder if the application my employer asked me to install for security purposes is hiding `Settings -> Developer Options`.

Comment: Yeah, it has to be enabled by going to Settings -> System -> About Phone -> Software Version, and tapping "Build Number" until it says you're a Developer. Sorry, lol -- forget it's not available by default because it's an autopilot thing for me on a new phone.

Comment: @l3l_aze that worked, thanks! You're welcome to copy your comment into an answer. Thanks Morrison too for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, enable Developer Options by going to Settings -> System -> About Phone -> Software Version and tapping "Build Number" until it says you're a developer.

Then, go to Settings -> Developer Options and enable "Show Touches".

This shows the small pointer/dot when you press on the screen, as is often seen in emulators.

There's some possibly-dangerous options here, so please make sure you understand what they do before trying them! :)

[image]